# Moved a Sitecore 6 site to production but got a Media.UploadWatcher Exception?

Tags: exception, web-config, sitecore, sitecore6

Has anyone seen an exception relating to the Media.UploadWatcher?  I don't have the error handy, but the exception was causing all pages to not load, even the admin section.  In order to fix it, I reset the application pool and the site came back up right away.

I know that the client was uploading some large files through the content editor, but I wouldn't think that alone would cause problems.  I have upped the `MaxExecutionTime` to allow for those uploads, but again, I don't think that would be the problem.  Is there something I forgot to do while moving the code to production or is there a setting that might be off?  All I did was copy the code to production, and change the directory references in the web.config to point to the new locations (like the license file).

There error hasn't come up again, but I'm scared it will come up at an inopportune time.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

The exception just occurred again on the live site and I had to recycle the app pool.  Anyone know what could be causing this?  Here is the exception from the event log:

> Event code: 3005
>   Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
>   Event time: 1/4/2010 9:56:50 AM
>   Event time (UTC): 1/4/2010 3:56:50 PM
>   Event ID: 7fbcc8d807204614904572753b4beb2e
>   Event sequence: 23
>   Event occurrence: 22
>   Event detail code: 0
>
> Application information:
>       Application domain: /LM/w3svc/1422107501/root-1-129070941106290901
>       Trust level: Full
>       Application Virtual Path: /
>       Application Path: C:\HostingSpaces\mysite\mysite.com\wwwroot\
>       Machine name: 180716WEB1
>
> Process information:
>       Process ID: 310020
>       Process name: w3wp.exe
>       Account name: 180716WEB1\myuser_web
>
> Exception information:
>       Exception type: TypeInitializationException
>       Exception message: The type initializer for 'Sitecore.Resources.Media.UploadWatcher' threw an exception.
>
> Request information:
>       Request URL: http://www.mysite.com/Default.aspx
>       Request path: /Default.aspx
>       User host address: 75.147.19.21
>       User:
>       Is authenticated: False
>       Authentication Type:
>       Thread account name: 180716WEB1\myuser_web
>
> Thread information:
>       Thread ID: 7
>       Thread account name: 180716WEB1\myuser_web
>       Is impersonating: False
>       Stack trace:
>
> Custom event details:
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the media uploadwatcher doesn't come in to it when using the content editor to add media - it runs on a schedule (defined in web.config) to check if any items have been added to the media upload folder in the filesystem (I can't remember the exact folder name at the moment).

When we've launched sitecore sites, we find it easier to NOT upload the local web.config to live - instead, duplicate changes to both. There are settings and entire sections in the web.config relevant to the role of that server.

If you can get the error message, add it to your post.

Comment: Added the exception, since it occurred again.  Ever seen that before?

Answer (score 0):

On our dev server the solution to this error was removing the SiteDefinition.config from the app_config/include folder, which only contains settings between xml comment (version 6.6 update 4) probably de default config file.

I Got there by first removing all the files in app_config/include and placing them back one by one.